# Background url( ) doesn't show up

Tags: css, background-image

My `background: url()` doesn't show any relative/absolute path in code.

[image: screenshot of an IDE]

Comment: Firstly, I advice you to delete space in your folder name, so replace "imagespart 2" to "imagespart2", maybe it can helps to solve your problem. And secondly, we need more codes than an image please, or a codepen or something similar ^^

Comment: delete that whole thing inside the url and write ../imagespart 2/ and you should see the item list.

Comment: But is there any way to do this with a bit less effort ? I mean by not writing/copying the whole ..../imagespart 2/item name... evreytime ? Using any one of relative/absolute path instead ?

Answer (score 0):

It's an example base on your link that work correctly, maybe you should remove space from image's name.

```css
body{
     background:url(https://marketplace.walkme.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/service2.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-size:cover;
     background-attachment:fixed;
}
```